# Cumulative calculation in window functions

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, window-functions

I have a question for window functions in **Postgresql**.

I have a table like the following where:

- each ID is unique
- `first_seen` is the first date the `ID` sees a message
- `even_time` is when the `ID` converts
- `cohort_week` is the first day of the week related to `first_seen`
- `range` is constructed based on `days_to_conv`: 1D - if `days_to_conv` is within 1 day, or 30 days or 90 days or 360 days.

| ID | first_seen | event_time | days_to_conv | cohort_week | range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1448 | 2018-08-20 | 2018-08-21 | 1 | 2018-08-20 | 1D |
| 1207 | 2018-08-20 | 2018-08-21 | 1 | 2018-08-20 | 1D |
| 1528 | 2018-08-25 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 1D |
| 1985 | 2018-08-22 | 2018-08-23 | 1 | 2018-08-20 | 1D |
| 1971 | 2018-08-23 | 2018-08-24 | 1 | 2018-08-20 | 1D |
| 1661 | 2018-08-25 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 1D |
| 1090 | 2018-08-23 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 1D |
| 1525 | 2018-08-25 | 2018-08-27 | 2 | 2018-08-20 | 30D |
| 1973 | 2018-08-25 | 2018-09-09 | 15 | 2018-08-20 | 30D |
| 1378 | 2018-08-20 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 30D |
| 1194 | 2018-08-22 | 2018-09-07 | 16 | 2018-08-20 | 30D |
| 1651 | 2018-08-25 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 30D |
| 1310 | 2018-08-23 | 2018-11-17 | 86 | 2018-08-20 | 90D |
| 1375 | 2018-08-20 | 2018-11-04 | 76 | 2018-08-20 | 90D |
| 1631 | 2018-08-25 | 2018-12-05 | 102 | 2018-08-20 | 360D |
| 1029 | 2018-08-22 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 360D |
| 1030 | 2018-08-25 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 360D |
| 1253 | 2018-08-20 | NULL | NULL | 2018-08-20 | 360D |

I want to create a calculation that creates a rolling cumulative ratio like the following, where:

- `size` is the amount of ID in that week
- `converted` is the sum of `NON NULL` entry in that range
- `ratio` is the ration between `converted` / `tot_size`
- ... and `cum_ratio` is the cumulative sum of `ratio`

| week | tot_size | range | converted | ratio | cum_ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-20 | 18 | 1D | 4 | 22.22% | 22.22% |
| 2018-08-20 | 18 | 30D | 3 | 16.67% | 38.89% |
| 2018-08-20 | 18 | 90D | 2 | 11.11% | 50.00% |
| 2018-08-20 | 18 | 360D | 1 | 5.56% | 55.56% |

I am having a hard time in understanding how to create `cum_ratio` for each `range` value.

I assume I have to apply a **window function** but I don't understand **how** to construct it.

Comment: If one of the answer below fits your needs, it could be good to mark it as solving your problem. You can also provide your own solution and mark it too. This way everyone knows the question was answered

Answer (score 0):

The `range` column type is problematic because it is difficult to sort properly. You need this in the definition of a window function, and you have to use a rather clunky expression for it.

```sql
select 
    cohort_week,
    total as tot_size,
    range, 
    converted,
    round(converted::numeric/ total* 100, 2) as ratio,
    round(sum(converted::numeric/ total* 100) over w, 2) as cum_ratio
from (
    select 
        cohort_week, 
        count(*),
        (
            select count(*) 
            from my_table s 
            where s.cohort_week = t.cohort_week
        ) as total,
        range, 
        count(event_time) as converted
    from my_table t
    group by cohort_week, range, total
    ) s
window w as (partition by cohort_week order by left(range, -1)::int)
order by cohort_week, left(range, -1)::int
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=635c1f6bc5eaca2917d778e26df1b012)

Comment: Thank you! Would it be easier if I defined the ranges as simply 1, 30, 90, 360? So it could be easily sorted?

Comment: Yes, I think an integer column would be better.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some final rounding or type casting may be done :

```
  with _temp as (
  select 
  distinct
  cohort_week::date,
  sum(1) over (PARTITION by extract ('week' from first_seen), extract('year' from first_seen)) as tot_size,
  first_value(range) over (PARTITION by range),
  sum(1) FILTER(where days_to_conv is not null) over (PARTITION by range) as converted
  from test
  )
  
  select 
  *,
  converted::float / tot_size as ratio,
  sum(converted::float / tot_size) over ( order by cohort_week rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
  from _temp order by cohort_week
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q3MF5Uanrgme5HFQcP2mK9/0

Answer (score -1):

On my side, I used the partitionning twice.
Once for keeping the *tot_size* along all the results and the second time to compute the cumulative ratio.

Finally, I get this

```sql
select
    cohort_week,
    tot_size,
    range,
    sum(days) as converted,
    ((sum(days)::float/tot_size)*100) ratio,
    sum((sum(days)::float/tot_size)*100) OVER (ORDER by sum(days) DESC) cum_ratio
FROM (
  select
    cohort_week,
    id,
    count(id) OVER (PARTITION by cohort_week) as tot_size,
    range,
    case
        when days_to_conv is null
             then 0
             else 1
        end days
    from my_table
    group by cohort_week, range,id
) T
group by cohort_week, range, tot_size;
```

Comment: this seems a very reasonable and clean solution! I will try this. I wonder now how can how generalize this kind of approach not only for 1D, 30D, 90D, 360D but for 1,2,3...360 days. Thanks! @Frédéric Praca

Comment: Wouldn't it only be the _days_to_conv_ field or did I miss something ?

Comment: The days_to_conv doesn't necessarily contain all the elements in the sequence 1,2,3...360. I was thinking about a way to generalize for all the elements - some of which, of course - will be 0. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I get it. So you could (left or right) join the result with a series of numbers. Something like WITH ranges as (select * from generate_series(1,360))